# Normality tests in C++ or java (statistics)

Tags: statistics

I am looking for a library in C/C++ or java (or easily callable from those) that implements statistical normality tests:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test

I had a quick look at boost and GSL, but they don't seem to include these.

I would appreciate links and examples how to use these tests (e.g. I am not sure how to link R libraries)

I would preferably work under Linux, but this is a secondary requirement.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test). It's pretty simple -- you sort your data to get an array containing the population CDF, and compute the ideal CDF for a normal distribution with the population mean + standard deviation. Then iterate over the array and calculate the maximum deviation between the population CDF and the ideal CDF. Then plug it into the K-S distribution for a given degree of confidence.

All but the last part is trivial to implement in either language -- in Java here's one class to do that from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/KolmogorovSmirnovDistributionImpl.html).

See my answer to [Benford's Law in Java - how to make a math function into Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815155/benfords-law-in-java-how-to-make-a-math-function-into-java/7820914#7820914) for more details (different distribution, same idea though).

Comment: I downloaded http://commons.apache.org/math/download_math.cgi, but the class KolmogorovSmirnovDistributionImpl seems not to be there :(. Which jars do I need to include?

Comment: Drat, it looks like it's in commons-math 3.0, which hasn't had an official release yet. >:( Dunno why they make their javadoc available before the .jar file. Anyway the source is here: http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math/distribution/KolmogorovSmirnovDistributionImpl.html

Comment: [Latest link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/KolmogorovSmirnovTest.html)